# Xcode 5 Project Stuck in Xcode 6 (Only in iOS 8)

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, ios8, xcode6

I have a AppStore uploaded app which i wants to Update for iOS 8.
But surprisingly my `selectors` for `UIButton` are not working properly (i.e. `Button` is not clickable some time) when i try to `Push` the screen.

So, when i navigate through other screen, Even back Button is also stuck. And after `POP` the entire `UI` for Home screen is not working(i.e. Stuck).

Selectors for Button's call after delay of 10 or more seconds. 
All this things happen only in iOS 8.

Please help me regarding this.

**UPDATE :**

My cpu memory usage after Navigate through Other screen jumps to 99% in iOS8.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing any network download in the viewDidLoad? Check for the same network download code piece in viewWillAppear of your corresponding view controllers.

There can be an issue of the not executing your UI kit operation on the main global queue.

Try to execute your UI operation on main queue, if you are returning from a background thread.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Your piece of execution code.
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.But it was working well & good in iOS 7. So,Let me try your code then will give you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your app on device. Some times this problem occurs on iOS8 simulator.

Comment: Little bit less But still stuck issue and memory warnings are appear in iOS 8.

Comment: Will you please add snippet of code ? It will be clear to me actually what happens

Comment: Not sure for which Due to which part it causing error, So can't add code of full Class :)